# Transpose cells on another tab and link back to original cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, transpose

I have a table I need to have in both the original and transposed views. However, I need to be able to update both sheets from ONE place.

**How can I duplicate transposed cells to a second sheet with their values linked to the first sheet?**

[image]

BEFORE:

- Sheet1 has Products in column A (original)

AFTER:

- Sheet1 has Poducts in column A (original)
- Sheet2 has Products in row A (transposed)
- Editing cell values in Sheet1 also updates Sheet2

Comment: Use Power Query (or a VBA routine, but PQ will be simpler to develop) to generate the table on the 2nd sheet.  Then, on the first sheet, use an event-triggered macro (eg worksheet_change)  to Update the query when the data changes.  You might even just use a `sheet_activate` event on the Sheet2 to trigger, depending on other requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Andrew I do not know how big is your data and in what frequency its updated; a few solutions coming to my mind.
1- You can link cells from sheet1 to sheet2 for once and then you are good to go as you typed in sheet1, values in sheet2 will be updated instantly.
2- You can manually `copy` your data and `paste special` it as `transposed`.
3- You can use the macro below to copy selected range and paste special it as transposed.  You will need to arrange the range to be pasted in the code according to your needs.  Results of macro will be like below screenshot.

[image]

```
Sub Macro3()
    Selection.Copy
    Range("a14").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a way to programmatically link cells on Sheet2 without setting the reference for each cell on Sheet1 individually?

Comment: It was something I needed before.  I tried to solve it as you said above but could not do and looked for another way.  It is something doable with coding if you have hundreds lines of data.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I prefer to always go for a solution with Excel built in function and no scripts. In your case that should be possible with a few limitations. Here's what you can do:

1. Complete your original table
2. On a new tab create a formula (assuming the source starts at cell A1 and the transposed area in the new tab also starts in A1. Otherwise adjust the references accordingly):

   =OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1, COLUMN(A1) - 1, ROW(A1) - 1)
3. Copy the formula to cover all the source's cells.
4. Optionally copy the formating with right click -> paste special -> Paste formats and transpose.

The limitations are:

- if you add or remove lines in your source area, you'll have to copy and paste the formula in your transposed area anew
- whenever you change the format in your source, you'll have to manually copy it over your transposed area as well
- if you have empty cells in your source, the transposed area will show these as `0`

Comment: So there's no simple way to do this with built-in Excel features? If not, then that's more what I was thinking -- a formula that links to Sheet1 while using the transposed cell locations.

Comment: More simple would be to use 'Paste Special', but this will not give you linked cells.

Comment: Yes, that would be ideal. I'm sad it doesn't handle links!

Answer (score 0):

As mentionned in a comment to your question, use the build-in tool [PowerQuery / Get & Transform](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/about-power-query-in-excel-7104fbee-9e62-4cb9-a02e-5bfb1a6c536a).
The [transpose](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/transpose-table) step is described on the docs.microsoft.com Website.
Before transposing, you may have to ["demote"](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/table-promote-demote-headers) the column header of the imported table.

To update the transposed table, you have to refresh it manually (DATA > refresh all).

Answer (score 0):

Select the Range and go to **Data**- **From Sheet**- open **Power Query Editor**- select **Color, Price, Note** columns- go to **Transform** tab and select **Unpivot Columns**- select **Name** column- under Transform tab- select Pivot Column- **Values Column: Value** and **Advanced options: Don't Aggregate**- click **OK** and **Close & Load to...**:
[image]